# How to install atom-autocomplete-php on atom editor?

Tags: php, xampp, atom-editor

I have XAMPP as a local server on Windows and works with Atom editor. When I try to install `atom-autocomplete-php` on my editor, I get these two errors:

1. > Failed to activate the atom-autocomplete-php
2. > Incorrect setup!

Can you help me please?

Comment: Seems to be an issue for that package: https://github.com/Peekmo/atom-autocomplete-php/issues/388 - If you have the same issue as that, you should contact the developers/write in that github issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to "install" composer and use the `php-composer-completion` package in Atom to get function autocomplete with parameter lists. I'm trying out Atom so maybe this isn't the exact answer you need, but it's what I needed.